# Not able to get email address from picked contact in android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-contentprovider, android-contacts

I am trying to pick a contact using intent in android. The information I need is name, phone no and email address of contact. following what I have tried so far.

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        // Check for the request code, we might be usign multiple startActivityForReslut
        switch (requestCode) {
            case RESULT_PICK_CONTACT:
                contactPicked(data);
                break;
        }
    }
}

private void contactPicked(Intent data) {
    Cursor cursor = null;
    try {
            // getData() method will have the Content Uri of the selected contact
        Uri uri = data.getData();
        //Query the content uri
        cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int phoneIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);
        int nameIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME);

        String phoneNo = cursor.getString(phoneIndex);
        String name = cursor.getString(nameIndex);
        String contactBookId = uri.getLastPathSegment();

        String email = null;
        try {
            Cursor emailCur
                    = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI,
                                                                null,
                                                                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID + " = ?",
                                                                new String[]{contactBookId}, null);
            emailCur.moveToFirst();
            while (emailCur.moveToNext()) {
                String phone = emailCur.getString(emailCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));
                int type = emailCur.getInt(emailCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE));
                String s = (String) ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.getTypeLabel(getActivity().getResources(), type, "");

                Log.d("TAG", s + " email: " + phone);
            }
            emailCur.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception while trying to fetch email addresses of " + name + ":" + e.getMessage());
        }
        cursor.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

here is how I am firing intent

```
Intent contactPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(contactPickerIntent, RESULT_PICK_CONTACT);
```

My problem is that emailCur never reads any email address. Code never enters in loop.

**Edit**

even If I ditch `getLastPathSegment()` and retrieve id as follows I get same behaviour

```
            int idIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID);
        String contactBookId = cursor.getString(idIndex);
```

Comment: Rather than rely on `getLastPathSegment()`, see if `CONTACT_ID` is one of the columns you get back in `cursor`.

Comment: @CommonsWare I had tried that as well as `_ID` bu no luck. I will try again and let you know.

Comment: @CommonsWare I tried it again without any luck. Also I have update my question with what I tried.

Comment: Use this link. It works for me. Hope works for you too. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34763352/how-to-get-a-email-for-particualr-phone-number/42548879#42548879

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
emailCur.moveToFirst();
while (emailCur.moveToNext()) {
...
}
```

You are moving the cursor two times before reading, and if the contact has 1 email never enters in the while loop.

Delete `emailCur.moveToFirst();`